# htaccess: How do I 301 redirect a sub-sub folder when folder names have spaces?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, whitespace

My goal is simple. But my ability sucks. I have changed the naming convention of my gallery (I use jAlbum)

The previous path was

/gallery/

and within gallery previously was

/Collection 1/

/Collection 2/
(and so on. Up to 11)

I needed to change the names, so they are now
/Homes Collection 1/
/Homes Collection 2/
and so on...

Example old full path:
`https://www.crown-point.com/gallery/Collection 1/`

Example new full path:
`https://www.crown-point.com/gallery/Homes Collection 1/`

I have tried many variations of Redirect and Rewrite and using \s or %20 but have failed to get the syntax correct. I've spent the better part of day hunting down a solution. But I can't get that blasted redirect to work correctly so that regardless of which old url gets the call, it will go to the new, correct one.

(I know, there shouldn't be any spaces in the names. But that's how jAlbum rolls.)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following redirect :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/gallery/Collection(.+)$  /gallery/Homes%20Collection$1
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply Amit! I will try that when I get to work tomorrow and will let you know!

Comment: Unfortunately, Amit, that redirect resolves to `https://www.crown-point.com/gallery/Homes%2520Collection%201/` "%2520" is now placed between "Homes" and "Collection" instead of %20.

Comment: Still hoping for an answer...anyone?

Comment: @user2188282 Are you getting a 404 error with this?